# What is the energy of one photon radiation? (Probably super basic for you)

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

So, this is given question:

> The radio station emits radiation power of 6 kW, wavelength 3 m.
>
> a) What is the energy of one photon radiation?
>
> b) How many photons are emitted in 5s?

I tried this:

[image]

But here I came across problems, I know that $h$ is constant, but don't know what is going to be with $c$ and $f$.

Comment: Hint: $c$ is a constant, and $c/f$ is given

Comment: c= 3*10^8 m/s ? and f=3m ?

Comment: @Psychotic We don't answer homework questions normally unless you explicitly write whatever you have tried. On the other hand, don't use _f_ for wavelength, since _f_ usually means frequency. $\lambda$ stands for wavelength.

Comment: @KV18 I did tried, but I always had problems with formulas and which one I should use for specific task. Btw. I just realized that I made mistake by that, that lambda is actually for wavelength...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By De Brogile's equation we have,
The energy of one Photon E as :
$$ E=h \nu $$
$$ E= \frac{hc}{ \lambda} $$
$$ E= \frac{6.626×10^{-34}×3×10^8}{ 3} $$
$$ E = 6.626×10^{-26} $$
The energy provided by the source in 5 seconds will be 
$$ P= \frac{E}{t} $$
$$ E= P×t $$
$$ E= 6×10^3 ×5$$
$$ E= 3 × 10^4 J $$
Now since the photons receive their energies from the source .
Let the number of photons emitted in 5 seconds be n  then 
$ \textit{ n×( energy of one Photon) = total energy supplied by the source} $
$$ n× 6.626×10^{-26}= 3×10^4 $$
$$ n= \frac{3×10^4}{6.626×10^{-26}} $$
$$ n= 4.53× 10^{29} $$

Comment: Please try not writing the whole answer if the OP has not fulfilled the "homework guidelines" which you can find on the website.

Comment: Okay I will take care of it next time

Comment: First to say thank you @HarshWasnik and I really appriciate this.
I have some questions, for the task in a) even I realized that I have to calculate E=? but I obviously had some struggles in calculating it, but for b)
How did you know that you first need to calculate E again, by the formula 
$$
P=E/t=E=P*t
And after that you used formula E=n*hf, but I can't really realize what represent n, our teacher just said it's integrer number, n=1,2,3... 
And why did you have to calculate again E=? when you calculated already in a

Comment: @KV18 Believe me I would rather done this 2 of 5 tasks that I understand them than finish all of them and don't know how to do any of them... So as I alredy said to you, I tried 3x times, and I have really big struggles with formulas, I don't know which exactly formula I need to use, and that's why I am asking for help...

Comment: Sure. But it is the standard way this website works. No question without adequate explanation as to what exactly it is that you don't understand is accepted here. When I joined stack exchange in my 10th grade, I used to get owned here in the beginning. Just giving an insight! :)

Comment: Okay, I get that is kind of unfair, in future I'll do my best to try to finish task, but sometimes I just have that basic struggles that I can't get rid of and my mind just blocks...

Comment: The E calculated in part a was the energy of one Photon whereas the E calculated in the second part was the total energy supplied by the source ie the radio station. The radio station emits a large number of photons. The energy calculated in second part is basically the summation of energies of individual photons . The 'n' actually is an integer.